# Can't get like to work in Oracle SQL because column name is a reserved word

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get a query to search for a string, and I'm pretty sure the only reason I am not getting it to work is because the name of the column is NAME which is also a reserved word.The query runs but it does not pull up anything even though the string is in the column. Is there anything that looks wrong?

```
SELECT TABLE."NAME"
FROM TABLE
WHERE TABLE."NAME" LIKE '%apple%'
```

Comment: `name` is not a reserved word in Oracle:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm.  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

It should work, just ensure you're using upper/lower case correctly.

```
create table tbl ("NAME" varchar(20));
insert into tbl values ('pppp apple pppp');
insert into tbl values ('pppp beer pppp');
insert into tbl values ('apple pppp pppp');

select *
from   tbl
where  tbl."NAME" like '%apple%'
```

> ```
> | NAME            |
> | :-------------- |
> | pppp apple pppp |
> | apple pppp pppp |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4d2eb5d74875a336c28b9fae06d7f432)*

Comment: I was using all caps which was the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure of the case of the data, force it by using upper or lower before comparing so you are comparing apples to apples (heh):

```
SELECT NAME
FROM TABLE
WHERE lower(NAME) LIKE '%apple%'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `table` *is* a reserved word.  Let me assume that is not the real table name.

Second, putting a column name in double quotes has an effect.  I would suggest that you try:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM <tablename> t
WHERE t.name LIKE '%apple%';
```